# How I can get secure url (https) of CMS page using url_key?

Tags: magento-1.7, cms, url, https, ssl

I have enable SSL and one of CMS is restricted for register users.

And this page is in footer.

If logged in user try to access without https it fails and redirect to my account.

I want that particular CMS page url alway secure ie https://

```
<?php echo $this->getUrl('page_url_key',array('_secure'=>true));?> is not working.
```

How I will get CMS page url alway secure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `_type => 'direct_link'`

`Mage::getUrl('page_url_key', array(
    '_nosid' => true,
    '_store' => 'default',
    '_type' => 'direct_link'
));`

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `_forced_secure` option for this:

```
Mage::getUrl('page_url_key', array('_forced_secure' => true));
```

See http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters for all options that you can use with getUrl.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that `_secure` will only use a secure URL if the corresponding controller's module is configured as such? (see `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml - frontend>secure_url node`)